# In Jekyll, how to change the capitalization rules for converting a file name into a blog post title?

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to change the capitalization of my blog posts titles in Jekyll, without having to type it in the yaml title field every time. By default, jekyll convert the file `2016-02-22-my-blog-title` to the title "My Blog Title", and I want it to be "My blog title".

I have noticed that I can achieve this behavior by modifying `_layouts/post.html`, and changing the line

```
<a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

to

```
<a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title | downcase | capitalize}}</a>
```

However, this makes it impossible to override the capitalization rules by adding a custom title to the yaml field when needed. For example, it is not possible to capitalize a proper noun that is not the first word of the title. Is it possible to change how the default title is generated from the file name, while still allowing this to be overridden when a title is specified in the yaml fron matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a plugin that overrides how Jekyll generates a title for posts.

This can be done by overriding Jekyll Utils module.

Create a **_plugins/titleize_overrride.rb** file containing :

```
module Jekyll
  module Utils
    def titleize_slug(slug)
      slug.split(/[_-]/).join(' ').capitalize
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: quick note: you have to restart the server for this to kick in.  The way this works is that jekyll takes all the *.rb files in _plugins, so this overwrites the function "titleize_slug" found here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/utils.rb

Answer (score 1):

To change this behavior you would have to use a custom plugin. [Paul Herron shows an example on his blog](http://paulherron.com/blog/custom_title_formatting_in_jekyll/) where he overrides the `titleized_slug` method.

```
class Jekyll::Post

  def titleized_slug
    self.slug.split(/[_-]/).join(' ').capitalize
  end
end
```

N.B. The post is from 2014, so some the code above might need to be tweaked to work with Jekyll v3.

Comment: This method is now in Jekyll Utils module.