# How to prevent my github page from making post title 'title-cased'

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I have created a github page and have chosen one of proposed Jekyll themes called `minima`. To add a post I have created a file called `2018-11-16-My-first-post-on-github.md`. However, the post title displayed is a text converted to title case: `My First Post On Github`, so every first letter in each word is made upper case. How can I prevent that? Is this theme-dependent?

Comment: It could be, `text-transform: capitalize` could be set in the styles.

Comment: Your repository url can be useful to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.toTitleCase = function(str){
  var smallWords = /^(a|an|and|as|at|but|by|en|for|if|in|nor|of|on|or|per|the|to|vs?\.?|via)$/i;

  return (str+'').replace(/[A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+[^\s-]*/g, function(match, index, title){
    if (index > 0 && index + match.length !== title.length &&
      match.search(smallWords) > -1 && title.charAt(index - 2) !== ":" &&
      (title.charAt(index + match.length) !== '-' || title.charAt(index - 1) === '-') &&
      title.charAt(index - 1).search(/[^\s-]/) < 0) {
      return match.toLowerCase();
    }

    if (match === 'tus') {
      return match;
    }

    if (match.substr(1).search(/[A-Z]|\../) > -1) {
      return match;
    }
    // Avoid uppercasing 'mod_deflate', apt-file - kvz
    if (match.match(/.[\_\-\/\d]./)) {
      return match;
    }
    // Avoid uppercasing '`frame`', '/sftp/import' - kvz
    if (match.match(/(^[`\/]|[`]$)/)) {
      return match;
    }
    // Avoid uppercasing: 'tmpfs' or anything that doesn't have a vowel - kvz
    if (!match.match(/[aeiou]/)) {
      return match;
    }

    return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1);
  });
};

exports.newPost = function (content, opts, cb){
  var self        = this;
  var matches     = [];
  var oldTitle    = '';
  var newTitle    = '';
  var oldLine     = '';
  var heading     = '';
  var newLine     = '';
  var changes     = [];
  var words       = [];
  var frontMatter = content.split('---')[1];

  if (frontMatter) {
    matches     = frontMatter.match(/^(title\s*:\s*)\"?(.+?)\"?[\ \t]*$/im);
    oldTitle    = matches[2];
    newTitle    = self.toTitleCase(oldTitle).trim();
    oldLine     = matches[0];
    newLine     = matches[1] + '"' + newTitle + '"';
    if (oldLine !== newLine) {
      changes.push({oldTitle: oldTitle, newTitle: newTitle});
      content = content.replace(oldLine, newLine);
    }
  }

  if (opts.body === true) {
    matches = content.match(/^\#{1,6} ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\;\!\?\%\&\;\:\.\/\(\)\ ]+)$/mg)
    for (var i in matches) {
      words       = matches[i].split(' ')
      heading     = words.shift();
      oldTitle    = words.join(' ');
      newTitle    = self.toTitleCase(oldTitle).trim();
      oldLine     = heading + ' ' + oldTitle;
      newLine     = heading + ' ' + newTitle;
      if (oldLine !== newLine) {
        changes.push({oldTitle: oldTitle, newTitle: newTitle});
        content = content.replace(oldLine, newLine);
      }
    }
  }


  if (changes.length === 0) {
    content = null;
  }

  return cb(null, content, changes);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll **automatically** converts your post title to uppercase upon import. You can fix this [by using a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975716/in-jekyll-how-to-change-the-capitalization-rules-for-converting-a-file-name-int), or by [using a YAML file](https://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/mydoc_yaml_tutorial.html) or [Front matter](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-jekyll/#front-matter-is-required) to [specify your title value directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487110/include-jekyll-liquid-template-data-in-a-yaml-variable?rq=1).